# REST API design of resources with many operations based on the resource status

Tags: rest

I am designing a REST API for user management that must support the following CRUD operations:

- create a new user (POST `/users`)
- update an existing user (PUT `/users/{userid}`)
- delete a user (DELETE `/users/{userid}`)
- get user details (GET `/users/{userid}`)

and operations that depend on the user status:

- activate a user
- block a user
- unblock a user
- suspend a user
- archive a user

The payload of the above requests does not contain a user representation. It contains information such as e.g. the reson why the is blocked/suspended/archived.

According to good REST design practises URIs should not API operations, so are there other ways than e.g. POST `/users/{userid}/activate` how such operations can be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Roy T. Fielding's dissertation, [any information that can be named can be a REST resource](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1):

> **5.2.1.1 Resources and Resource Identifiers**
>
> The key abstraction of information in REST is a resource. Any information that can be named can be a resource: a document or image, a temporal service (e.g. "today's weather in Los Angeles"), a collection of other resources, a non-virtual object (e.g. a person), and so on. In other words, any concept that might be the target of an author's hypertext reference must fit within the definition of a resource. A resource is a conceptual mapping to a set of entities, not the entity that corresponds to the mapping at any particular point in time. [...]

Since the *status* belongs to a *user*, the *status* can be managed as a **sub-resource** of the *user* resource.

To achieve it, you could have a URL like `/users/{userid}/status`.

[`POST`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) or [`PUT`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) can be performed on this URL sending the relevant information to change the *user status*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can a user status be a separate resource? It is an integral part of the user. It does not have its own identity. You cannot create a user status without a user. How do you e.g. block a user, you call PUT `/users/{userid}/status` with JSON `{"command":"block"}`?

Comment: @AdamSiemion I just updated my answer: since the *status* belongs to a *user*, the *status* can be managed as a **sub-resource** of the *user* resource. To update the user status, just perform a `PUT` on `/users/{userid}/status` sending the *status*. I'm not sure about the `command` property. I would use `value` or `status`.

Comment: Ok, I see. I think what you are suggesting is level 0 in the Richardson Maturity Model - one URI, one HTTP verb. Regardless what operation you want to invoke, block/unblock/archive you always call the same URI `/users/{userid}/status`.

Comment: @AdamSiemion I think it's more related to [level 1](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level1) and  [level 2](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level2). Anyway, I think it will make your API easier to use.

Comment: This has a lot of disavantages, because you need to parse the payload to get the operation that was called, from the code perspective the most harmful one being - you have to introduce a lot of boilerplate code for payload parsing, when you have a separate method for each operation, each of these methods can take a different class as an argument, then it is the responsibility of the framework to deserialize the  received payload and create a new instance of your request class, now when you have one method you have to do it yourself

Comment: @AdamSiemion Unfortunately, I cannot see another way to design it in a "*RESTful way*". I don't know your stack but, if you are using Java, for example, JSON parsing frameworks such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) can minimize the boilerplate code for payload parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible options are for example:

- model the action to be a part of the user resource (e.g. introduce an archived-Flag that can be set). With this approach its quirky to pass additional event-information (reason why he was archived/blocked/...), of course.
- create a separate REST-resource, e.g. `/api/archivedUsers/` where you can POST a tuple consisting of user-URI and additional event-data

both approaches have in common, that they try to model the state of your user object (REST-like), rather than performing an action on it (what feels RPC-like). You could also check this article: [REST API design resource modeling](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/rest-api-design-resource-modeling).